# Library resolve dependency at runtime what is the right approach?

Tags: c, module, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I'm writing some Application in C. It will run on a Linux machine.
My application has some dependency in lets say libA.
Lets say that libA API is this:

```
int libAfunc();
```

I want to be able to compile my app with dynamic link to libA and then run the same binary even if libA is unavailable. I'm not sure how to do it.

I thought to create a "default" implementation of libA API, it will be part of my application code.
Then I thought to create some module that has a link to my App and to libA and to remove the dependency of my App to libA. I will use `dlopen` to open this module in my App and in the module constructor I will replace somehow my default implementation with libA API.

1. I'm not sure if its the right approach.
2. I'm not sure how to replace my mock function with the real function, maybe use function pointers, and add some setters to my App and expose them? Using the setters, the module constructor will be able to change the functions.

Comment: You need to use functions like `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` to access the library dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Not sure I understand which library you referring to and how it will help me.

Comment: They're part of the `libdl` library. But now I see that you mention that in the question.

Comment: You don't use dlopen to open your module, you use dlopen to load `libA`.

Comment: So I don't need the module?
Load the lib at runtime using dlopen().
On success use lib API with dlsym(). On failure use "default" API?

Comment: yeah, that's the basic idea.

Comment: If you need this in multiple programs, you could put that logic in the module, which would be linked to all those programs.

Comment: I think it's a good idea. This way I will be able to use this lib elsewhere.
So the module will implement the lib API and expose it. It will load it using dlopen. On success will call lib functions, on failure his own implementation. Apps will be compiled with dynamic link to the module.

Comment: yes, that's the way to go. The module is just a way to encapsulate this.